# Regex match with any special character and newline

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to decode a multi-line binary file that has Protobuf encoded data (may contain the new line, special characters, etc.). The file contains a special character to split each sequence of data.
The delimiter is `###` and I write data like `"###" + data` to file.
Suppose this input:

```
###AB
CD###EFGHI###J
KLM
```

And I need the output be like `["AB\nCD", "EFGHI", "J\nKLM"]`. I tried the `^###(.*)$` pattern with `flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL` but didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you need `re` for this, regular `str.split` will do:

```
>>> text = '''###AB
    CD###EFGHI###J
    KLM'''

>>> list(filter(bool, text.split('###')))
['AB\nCD', 'EFGHI', 'J\nKLM']
```

If you expect variable amount of various special chars:

```
>>> list(filter(bool, re.split(r'[^\s\w]+', text)))
['AB\nCD', 'EFGHI', 'J\nKLM']
```